# I/O ERROR: SOCKET ERRORS

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee

We have J2EE Web application deployed on JBOSS 4.0.2 server. From last few days The application suddenly stops. 
we are getting following errors in log.

> java.net.SocketException: Software
>   caused connection abort: recv failed

Due to above socket errors application is not able to connect database.
Restarting jboss application also does not help. To resolve socket error we have to restart production machine.
After restarting production machine it works perfectly.

What could be reason for above socket errors?

Comment: Looks like a problem on DB side. Did you check errors in DB logs?

Comment: Is it due to closed DB connection? Looks like you have a firewall issue.

Comment: We are using Windows 2003 64 bit Server. Using Jboss 4.0.2 as application Server, JDK Version 1.6.18 64 bit and apache 2.2.15 as webserver.

There are other application instances which are connected to the same database and working fine.

To test this DB connection issue, we deployed a jsp in another ear but under the same application server instance which successfully connects to the database server.

Please let us know for any additional information required. Looking for a response and a resolution to this ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

That error essentially means somebody tried to read or write from a closed socket (it's Windows speak for "connection reset"). There are a lot of reasons that can happen though, and it's impossible to say exactly why your application is doing it. Some things you might try checking:

- if you have multiple threads reading and writing to the same socket, make sure one of them isn't closing it
- try turning off [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm); I've seen this error happen because someone closed the socket before the OS finished writing to it (you can do that with [setTcpNoDelay](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTcpNoDelay%28boolean%29))